# Smoothness of the flow associated to the one-parameter subgroup of Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\Gamma$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ and $\{g^t\}$ be a one-parameter subgroup of $G$.

Consider $\phi(\Gamma x, t):=\Gamma x g^t$. I wonder if $\phi:\Gamma \backslash G \times \mathbb R \to \Gamma \backslash G$ is automatically a smooth map (so that $\phi_t$ gives a smooth flow).

The key part is that whether $\{g^t\}$ has smooth properties immediately. Unfortunately I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: Is your only question is weather the one parameter subgroup $s:\mathbb{R}\to G$ given by $s(t)=g^t$, is smooth?

Comment: @Kajelad  my question is whether the flow is smooth. But I think one may have to address the smoothness of s(t) first

Comment: What definition of a one-parameter subgroup are you using? They are usually taken to be smooth by definition.

Comment: @kajelad Just $g^t g^s=g^{t+s}$.

Comment: @kajelad actually I don't know how to show $\phi$ is smooth even if we assume that $s$ is smooth.

Comment: If the one parameter subgroup $s:\mathbb{R}\to G$ is smooth, composing with multiplication (on the right) gives a smooth map $\mathbb{R}\times G\to G$ given by $(g,t)\mapsto gs(t)$. Composing this with the projection gives a smooth map $\mathbb{R}\times G\to\Gamma\backslash G$. Since it is constant on fibers, this map descends smoothly to the quotient, giving $\phi:\mathbb{R}\times\Gamma\backslash G\to\Gamma\backslash G$.